# Support for Magento Commerce 2.2.x ends on December 31, 2019. Any Idea When Support for 2.3.x Will End?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Thats is in a few days. 2.3 will go EOL quite fast I suspect.
I am considering migration of my e-commerce site to Magento2. Question: Isn't it wiser to wait a bit until a version has a LTS ? Magento2 versions seem to have short life cycles..I am wondering why.

Answer (score 1):

a problem with code, new features, APIs and third-party applications.
You should not run anything below 2.3.3 (the latest version) and be ready to instantly upgrade when new version comes in.

The software and development stack changes every week. new features, bug fixes, etc.

what's the point of wasting developer resources on functions that are deprecated and no longer exist due to changes in the entire stack.

The problem with magento shop owners is that they have no idea how to keep their store and web stack in **Drop-in replacement** mode. when you can type `composer update` and everything will be updated. and you dont have to think about some

There are many stores that work in version 2.1, and they will not be able to upgrade without rewriting all their code.

don't think when support for a particular version of a branch ends. Keep your stack well organized.